# Error: Statement Function is recursive

Tags: recursion, module, fortran, fortran90, subroutine

This is trying to solve a linear equation of 3*3 and print out the results, but it got problems in the commented lines:

I defined the module LinearSolution outside of program, should I define it inside? what's the difference?

Why it says the statement is recursive, you know, when I use these statement as normal subroutine instead of module subroutine, they are verified to be fine.

```
module LinearSolution
    type LAE
        integer::N
        double precision,dimension(:,:),allocatable::A
        double precision,dimension(  :),allocatable::B
    contains
        procedure,nopass::RowReduction
    end type LAE
contains
    subroutine RowReduction
        double precision::C
        do k=1,N
            do i=k+1,N
                if(A(k,k)/=0) then
                    C=A(i,k)/A(k,k)
                    B(i)=B(i)-B(k)*C       !error: Statement Function is recursive
                    do j=k+1,N
                        A(i,j)=A(i,j)-A(k,j)*C   !error: Statement Function is recursive
                    end do
                end if
            end do
        end do

        do k=N,1,-1
            do i=k-1,1,-1
                if(A(k,k)/=0) then
                    C=A(i,k)/A(k,k)
                    B(i)=B(i)-B(k)*C  !error: Statement Function is recursive
                end if
            end do
        end do

        do k=1,N
            if(A(k,k)/=0) then
                B(k)=B(k)/A(k,k)  !error: Statement Function is recursive
            end if
        end do
    end subroutine RowReduction
end module LinearSolution

program TestLAE
    use LinearSolution  !fatal error: cant open module file LinearSolution.mod for reading
    type(LAE)::LAE1
    LAE1%N=3
    allocate(LAE1%B(1:N))
    allocate(LAE1%A(1:N,1:N))
    LAE1%B=(/1,1,1/)
    LAE1%A=(/2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2/)
    call LAE1%RowReduction
    print*, LAE1%B(1),LAE1%B(2),LAE1%B(3)
end program
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is so often the case, `implicit none` is your friend.

Let's take the errors one at a time:

```
B(i)=B(i)-B(k)*C       !error: Statement Function is recursive
```

the compiler doesn't recognize `B` in this context; there is no variable declared `B` here(*), so the best it can do is assume that it's a real-valued [statement function](http://www.obliquity.com/computer/fortran/function.html) defining B as a function of I.   Statement functions are space saving but confusing ways of defining a function inline, but amongst other things they can't be recursive; here you'd be defining `B(i)` in terms of `B(i)` which obviously fails.

(*) But!  you cry.  `B` is an array field in my type `LAE`!  Yes, but we're not in the context of LAE here; and indeed, in the context of this function there are no variables of type `LAE` to even use the B values of.   This is because the procedure was defined `nopass`; you need to have a variable which is the object being operated on which is of class `LAE` so that we can access those fields.   That looks something like this:

```
    type LAE
        !...
    contains
        procedure::RowReduction
    end type LAE

contains
    subroutine RowReduction(self)
        class(LAE), intent(InOut) :: self
        double precision::C
        integer :: i, j, k
        do k= 1, self%N
            do i= k+1, self%N
                if( self%A(k,k) /= 0 ) then
        !....
```

Note that we have to define self to be of `class(LAE)` rather than type; class is a superset of type and is needed when dealing with extensible objects which include those with (re-)allocatable components.   Note too we've added implicit none which would tell you right away that `B` wasn't defined, and thus specified the integer indices i,j, and k.

Once `N`, `A`, and `B` are being correctly referenced as fields of `self`, then most of the rest of the program is correct.  Note that you have to `reshape` your `LAE1%A` array:

```
LAE1%A=reshape((/2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2/), (/N, N/))
```

But otherwise things seem fine.

```
module LinearSolution
implicit none

    type LAE
        integer::N
        double precision,dimension(:,:),allocatable::A
        double precision,dimension(  :),allocatable::B
    contains
        procedure::RowReduction
    end type LAE

contains
    subroutine RowReduction(self)
        class(LAE), intent(InOut) :: self
        double precision::C
        integer :: i, j, k
        do k= 1, self%N
            do i= k+1, self%N
                if( self%A(k,k) /= 0 ) then
                    C = self%A(i,k) / self%A(k,k)
                    self%B(i) = self%B(i)- self%B(k)*C
                    do j=k+1, self%N
                         self%A(i,j) = self%A(i,j) - self%A(k,j)*C
                    end do
                end if
            end do
        end do

        do k = self%N,1,-1
            do i=k-1,1,-1
                if( self%A(k,k)/=0) then
                    C= self%A(i,k)/ self%A(k,k)
                    self%B(i)= self%B(i)- self%B(k)*C
                end if
            end do
        end do

        do k=1, self%N
            if( self%A(k,k)/=0 ) then
                self%B(k) = self%B(k) / self%A(k,k)
            end if
        end do
    end subroutine RowReduction
end module LinearSolution

program TestLAE
    use LinearSolution
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: N = 3
    type(LAE)::LAE1
    LAE1%N=N
    allocate(LAE1%B(1:N))
    allocate(LAE1%A(1:N,1:N))
    LAE1%B=(/1,1,1/)
    LAE1%A=reshape((/2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2/), (/N, N/))
    call LAE1%RowReduction
    print*, LAE1%B(1),LAE1%B(2),LAE1%B(3)
end program
```

Running gives:

```
$ gfortran -o lae lae.f90 -Wall -std=f2003
$ ./lae
  0.50000000000000000       0.50000000000000000       0.50000000000000000
```

Comment: good call, though i cant agree that's the best the compiler can do. The actual error (undeclared array) is far more obvious than a bad statement function.  Does modern fortran even allow statement functions interspersed among executables?

Comment: @george: I agree; I was able to reproduce the error with gfortran 4.7.2, but ifort 13 gave me an undeclared array/function error for `B` and assumed `A` to be an external function name. Statement functions are only allowed in specification sections, but are of course obsolescent.